# regex 2 numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I pull out the 2 numbers in-between `Price Our:`
and the following  `|` from this string?

```
"Delivery: Price => 30.00 - 45.00 | Price Our: 1900.00 => 1800.00 | Delivery: Contact => 3 - 4 Days | "
```

I tried `(Price Our:.*?(?=\|))` But thats the limit of my regex knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 capture groups:

```
\bPrice Our: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) => (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \|
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bPrice Our:`  A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match `Price Our:`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 1, match a number with an optional decimal part
- `=>` Match literally
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 2, match a number with an optional decimal part
- `\|` Match  `|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3eRWUo/1)

```js
const s = "Delivery: Price => 30.00 - 45.00 | Price Our: 1900.00 => 1800.00 | Delivery: Contact => 3 - 4 Days | ";
const regex = /\bPrice Our: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) => (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \|/;
const match = s.match(regex);

if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  console.log(match[2]);
}
```

In case the digits are at the end of the string, and there is no  `|` following, you can account for that using an alternation to assert the end of the string:

```
\bPrice Our: (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) => (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: \||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2BlVS/1)

Answer (score 1):

### `(\d*\.\d+)`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) explanation:

[image]

```js
const regex = /(\d*\.\d+)/gm;
const str = "Delivery: Contact => 3 - 4 Days | Price Our: 1900.00 => 1800.00 | Delivery: Contact => 3 - 4 Days | ";

const res = str.match(regex)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: what if their are other numbers in the string I want specifically from ```Price our:``` to the following ```|```